# Join two SQL tables with each other using two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

**Problem:**

I am trying to "translate" the id in two columns in a grading table (betyg_essays) to the real names of those users in another table (betyg_users).

**The grading table (betyg_essays) look like this:**

[image]

**The user table (betyg_users) looks like this:**

[image]

**PHP code (so far):**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM betyg_essays JOIN betyg_users ON betyg_essays.Examiner = betyg_users.UID';
```

Examiner/Supervisor columns (betyg_essays) correspond to the UID column (betyg_users).

**Desired output should be (using the Firstname/Lastname columns):**

1. Examiner: John Hopkins. Supervisor: Mike Baker.
2. Examiner: John Hopkins. Supervisor: Mike Baker.

**Non-working SQL query:**

```
$query = "SELECT 
            (u1.Firstname + ' ' + u1.Lastname) AS Examiner, 
            (u2.Firstname + ' ' + u2.Lastname) AS Supervisor
        FROM betyg_essays grade
            INNER JOIN betyg_users u1 ON grade.Examiner = u1.UID
            INNER JOIN betyg_users u2 ON grade.Supervisor = u2.UID";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
CONCAT(u1.FirstName, ' ', u1.LastName) AS Examiner,
CONCAT(u2.FirstName, ' ', u2.LastName) AS Supervisor
FROM betyg_essays e
INNER JOIN betyg_users u1 ON e.Examiner = u1.UID
INNER JOIN betyg_users u2 ON e.Supervisor = u2.UID
```

I didn't tried the code, you might need to make some adjustments.

UPDATE: Fixed the id's

```
INNER JOIN betyg_users u2 ON e.Supervisor = u2.UID
```

UPDATE2:

I have changed the + to CONCAT function. Apparently, MySQL handles string differently then SQL Server.

Comment: I have tried your code but the output just gives me 0 0 and 0 0. I have updated the code I am using in the question.

Comment: @kexxcream I have changed my answer, I didn't knew that mysql dont allow + operation on numbers only :/

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to join user_table two times first for getting examiner user name and second for supervisor username

```
SELECT (g1.FirstName + ' ' + g1.LastName) AS Examiner,' , (g2.FirstName + ' ' + g2.LastName) AS Supervisor
FROM grading_table grade
INNER JOIN user_table g1 ON grade.examiner = g1.uid
INNER JOIN user_table g2 ON grade.supervisor = g2.uid
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to combine the first- and lastname in Examiner and Supervisor.

Comment: you are welcome. I have updated my answer, it will give you combine first name and last name

Answer (score 2):

**Final solution:**

```
$query = "SELECT 
            CONCAT (u1.Firstname, ' ', u1.Lastname) AS Examiner, 
            CONCAT (u2.Firstname, ' ', u2.Lastname) AS Supervisor
        FROM betyg_essays grade
            INNER JOIN betyg_users u1 ON grade.Examiner = u1.UID
            INNER JOIN betyg_users u2 ON grade.Supervisor = u2.UID";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(betyg_users.`Firstname`," ",betyg_users.`Lastname`) AS `examiner_name`,
CONCAT(betyg_users.`Firstname`," ",betyg_users.`Lastname`) AS `superviser_name`
FROM `betyg_essays`
INNER JOIN `betyg_users` ON betyg_essays.`Examiner` = betyg_users.`UID` 
INNER JOIN `betyg_users` ON betyg_essays.`Supervisor` = betyg_users.`UID`;
```

Comment: This works great but I am looking to combine Firstname/Lastname in Examiner and Supervisor.